# Big(O) notation - which one is correct

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o

I am trying to learn Big(O) notation. While searching for some articles online, I came across two different articles , [A](https://www.rithmschool.com/courses/javascript-computer-science-fundamentals/introduction-to-big-o-notation) and [B](http://www.leda-tutorial.org/en/official/ch02s02s03.html)

Strictly speaking in terms of loops - it seems that they almost have the same kind of flow. 
For example

[A]'s code is as follows (its done in JS)

```
function allPairs(arr) {
    var pairs = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            pairs.push([arr[i], arr[j]]);
        }
    }

    return pairs;
}
```

[B]'s code is as follows (its done in C)- entire code is [here](http://www.leda-tutorial.org/en/official/ch02s02s01.html#def.SortingByMinimumSearch)

```
  for(int i = 0; i < n-1 ; i++) {
    char min = A[i]; // minimal element seen so far
    int min_pos = i; // memorize its position
    // search for min starting from position i+1
    for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) 
      if(A[j] < min) {
        min = A[j];
        min_pos = j;
      }
    // swap elements at positions i and min_pos
    A[min_pos] = A[i];
    A[i] = min;
  }
```

The article on site A mentions that time complexity is O(n^2) while the article on site B mentions that its O(1/2·n2).

Which one is right?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that O(1/2·n2) means O(1/2·n^2), the two time complexity are equal. Remember that Big(O) notation does not care about constants, so both algorithms are O(n^2).

Comment: What makes example B `O(1/2 n^2)`?

Comment: There are two nested loop, this is sufficient to say that it is O(n^2). I don't care the meaning of that 1/2 constant, because as I said before, constants are not important for Big-O notation.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't read carefully. Article B says that the algorithm performs about N²/2 comparisons and goes on to explain that this is O(N²).